# MVC Core 1.1 - Image will not show on View, cannot find path or something.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, model-view-controller

Long time .NET developer, but novice when it comes to MVC.  Using MVC Core 1.1.

I have added a Content folder and an image file.  I have used URL.Content and straight  tags as well.  Image always shows as the 'boxed X' symbol.  This has humbled me greatly.

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>
<h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>

<img src="~/Content/santa.jpg" alt="Sample Image"  />
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/santa.jpg")" />
<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
```

Solution Explorer image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDhf2.jpg)

I appreciate any help here.  I don't get it.  Using VS 2017 Enterprise.

Comment: Not sure but check that In the solution explorer the image is set as Content under properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET core, static files are served from only the `wwwroot` folder by default. That means if you try to access a file from `~/Contents`, which is a directory in your app root, it won't work.

The good news is, You can configure the static file location as you wish. So update your `Configure` method in the `Startup` class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                                                           ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     // Your existing code goes here

     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
     {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
              Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Content")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Images")
     });
}
```

Now these images can be accessed from the browser like this `yourSiteName/Images/santa.jpg`

```
<img src="~/Images/santa.jpg" alt="Sample Image"  />
```

You may also consider moving the images to the `wwwroot` directory because the ASP.NET team added that directory for purposes like this ( static assets). I strongly recommend this.

If you move your image files to a folder called `images` inside the `wwwroot` directory, you can simply use `~/images/santa.jpg` and it will work without the above custom configuration we did.

```
<img src="~/images/santa.jpg" alt="Sample Image"  />
```

Comment: I love you so much.  haha.  Thank you.  This is another thing that totally escaped me while taming this beast known as MVC.